# When will select query aquire ExclusiveLock and RowExclusiveLock in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, locking

According to [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES), select query only need sharelock, but I found my select query acquired Exclusive lock. How did it happen? Here is my select query:

```
select gc.id 
from group_access_strategy ga
  left outer join person_group pg on gp.person_group_id=pg.id 
where gp.id=3
```

what is different from [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES) is that I added left join.

Comment: "group_access_strategy" doesn't appear in the docs at all, so obviously it is not just a left join which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you ran another command like `ALTER TABLE person_group ...`  (Access Exclusive) or an `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` (Row exclusive) in the same [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html). Locks will persist until a transaction is completed or aborted.

So if you ran:

```sql
BEGIN; --BEGIN starts the transaction
UPDATE group_access_strategy SET column = 'some data' where id = 1;
SELECT
  gc.id,
FROM
  group_access_strategy ga
  LEFT OUTER JOIN person_group pg ON (gp.person_group_id = pg.id)
WHERE
  pg.id = 3
```

The `UPDATE` statement would have created a Row Exclusive Lock that will not be released until you end the transaction by:

Saving all of the changes made since `BEGIN`:

```sql
COMMIT;
```

OR

nullifying any of the effects of statements since `BEGIN` with

```sql
ROLLBACK;
```

If you're new to Postgres and typically run your queries in an IDE like PG Admin or DataGrip, the `BEGIN` / `COMMIT` `ROLLBACK` commands are issued behind the scenes for you when you click the corresponding UI buttons.